# Make user-defined types true/false in boolean context in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, boolean-operations

I have a `Line` that represents the relevant information of a line on the cartesian plane. The type that has, among other members, a `bool` that indicates whether the slope is defined. I would like to be able to do the following:

```
if(my_line){
   double new_slope = my_line.slope * 9;
}
```

where the instance `my_line` itself is implicitly converted to a true/false value in a boolean context. I am thinking of the behavior I see with smart pointers, where if it is pointing to `nullptr` or `0`, the instance is considered false as-is.

How would I go about emulating this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Line` class, implement a `bool` conversion operator.  You could also optionally overload the [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical), but that is not required in C++11 and later.  See [Contextual conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions).

For example:

```
class Line {
    bool mSlopeDefined;
    ...

public:
    ...

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return mSlopeDefined;
    }

    // optional since C++11, but doesn't hurt...
    bool operator!() const {
        return !mSlopeDefined;
    }
};
```